next js returns not-found.tsx when image path is broken
I have a question: I have a Next.js project on app router, there is a page on which there is an image from the public folder.
If you go to the url of the picture (open it in a new tab window) and intentionally break the path of the image - next js shows not-found.tsx page?
Is there any way to fix this so that it just shows the default not-found error from next on a black screen?

Nothing to "fix", if you want a different design of the 404 page, update the not-found.tsx

no, i mean can we handle so it does not show my not-found.tsx page but show standard next.js not found page in such cases when image path is broken?
Or what is the best practice to do when public image path is broken?

Do you mean that you want a different page for pictures than the app?

yes, i just need standard 404 page that comes by default from next.js (black page with text "not found")

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From the comments, I think you want the "old" 404 page that was auto created in the pages router. I'm not sure if it still exists but you need to use:
import Error from 'next/error'
//...
export default function NotFound() {
  return <Error statusCode={404} />
}

This needs to go into the root not-found.tsx
Now, you need to switch between this and your current content for not-found and you have 2 options:

programatically by checking the path
create a group in the app folder and move existing not-found.tsx in there then create a new one with the "old" design.

Personally, I prefer option 2 as I like the code to be kept as clean as possible but I guess there is no real advantages to one or the other.
If the next/error import doesn't exist any more, you just need to create the page as you want it in the root.

sorry, my fault, I was wrong about what result I needed.
I need so if the mage path from assets is broken -  it shows 404 not found error from server, i mean error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
I know that assets comes from frontend, but is there a way to get this error instead of not-found page?

With solution number 1
